# How to hide the [@] in a Minecraft command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As most Minecraft command blocks makers know, if we use the `/say` command to output text, this will happen:

> [@]Lorem ipsum

The `[@]` is actually very annoying, how can I remove it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to output text into chat without the `[@]` you could use the tellraw command. The tellraw command lets you output whatever you like to chat using JSON however it sends the message to a specific player or players. To make it seem like it is just going into chat you could use the `@a` selector where you specify the player.

Here is an example that says Lorem ipsum:

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"Lorem ipsum"}
```

To make it say something different just change the "Lorem ipsum" to what you would like the command block to say. Don't forget to put it in "quotation" marks.

### EDIT

the `/tellraw` command is an extremely powerful tool and there are many things you can do with it other than this. It is useful because it can be used to output text with formatting such as different colours, bold, italics, and on-click actions in addition to being able to use selectors to output entity names.

When using JSON it is useful to know how it is structured. You can read about the structure of JSON at [JSON.org](http://json.org).

There is a great thread about the JSON Text Component for minecraft here which will help if writing your own `/tellraw` command or there are tools online like [this](http://minecraft.tools/en/tellraw.php) that will help generate the command for you.

Comment: Since Minecraft uses JSON, it's a good idea to visit http://www.json.org/ to check how it is strctured. Also, here's a list of other commands for Minecraft 1.9 (don't know which one's the latest): http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/351959-1-9-json-text-component-for-tellraw-title-books (it includes tons of things about `/tellraw`)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel 1.12 is in development. 1.9 commands may be significantly out of date.

Comment: @Tim Still, the most basic stuff may work, no? Like, text color and styling. But there's tools like http://minecraft.tools/en/tellraw.php which can generate the command. That should take care of incompatibilities, right?

Comment: but remember you have to escape `"`->`\"` and \->\\

Comment: @RomanGräf thanks! I'll put that in my answer as it definitely worth noting for those new to JSON.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel @Tim As the author of the thread, I will say that the text component has not received new features since 1.9, except for a new `keybind` string in the in-dev version 1.12. The thread is quite long and a pain to edit so I'll only add the keybind feature once 1.12 is released, but other than that there are essentially no differences.

Comment: @Skylinerw In all honesty, I haven't played Minecraft since 1.8.x, so, I know almost nothing at this point. Also, I just threw a quick Google-fu and found your thread very quckly.

Comment: the only thing outdated about 1.9 commands now is basically the new entity names from 1.11, but not much else.

Comment: With all that was said here, is it safe to say that the answer is incomplete? No information what-so-ever was added about the JSON format (only that double-quotes must be escaped)  and absolutely bare minimum information was added about the `/tellraw` command, as it is now.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I agree, I will try to put it into my answer.